# Split PDF into separate files based on text

Tags: pdf, split

I have a *large single pdf document* which consists of *multiple records*. Each record usually takes one page however some use 2 pages. A record starts with a defined text, always the same.

My goal is to *split this pdf* into separate pdfs and the split should happen always before the "header text" is found.

Note: I am looking for a tool or library using java or python. Must be free and available on `Win 7`.

Any ideas? AFAIK `imagemagick` won't work for this. May `itext` do this? I never used and it's
 pretty complex so would need some hints.

EDIT:

Marked Answer led me to solution. For completeness here my exact implementation:

```
public void splitByRegex(String filePath, String regex,
        String destinationDirectory, boolean removeBlankPages) throws IOException,
        DocumentException {

    logger.entry(filePath, regex, destinationDirectory);
    destinationDirectory = destinationDirectory == null ? "" : destinationDirectory;
    PdfReader reader = null;
    Document document = null;
    PdfCopy copy = null;
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);        

    try {
        reader = new PdfReader(filePath);
        final String RESULT = destinationDirectory + "/record%d.pdf";
        // loop over all the pages in the original PDF
        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {

            final String text = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i);
            if (pattern.matcher(text).find()) {
                if (document != null && document.isOpen()) {
                    logger.debug("Match found. Closing previous Document..");
                    document.close();
                }
                String fileName = String.format(RESULT, i);
                logger.debug("Match found. Creating new Document " + fileName + "...");
                document = new Document();
                copy = new PdfCopy(document,
                        new FileOutputStream(fileName));
                document.open();
                logger.debug("Adding page to Document...");
                copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, i));

            } else if (document != null && document.isOpen()) {
                logger.debug("Found Open Document. Adding additonal page to Document...");
                if (removeBlankPages && !isBlankPage(reader, i)){
                    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, i));
                }
            }
        }
        logger.exit();
    } finally {
        if (document != null && document.isOpen()) {
            document.close();
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
}

private boolean isBlankPage(PdfReader reader, int pageNumber)
        throws IOException {

    // see http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/Detecting-blank-pages-td2144877.html
    PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.getPageN(pageNumber);
    // We need to examine the resource dictionary for /Font or
    // /XObject keys.  If either are present, they're almost
    // certainly actually used on the page -> not blank.
    PdfDictionary resDict = (PdfDictionary) pageDict.get(PdfName.RESOURCES);
    if (resDict != null) {
        return resDict.get(PdfName.FONT) == null
                && resDict.get(PdfName.XOBJECT) == null;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: iText can do what you want if the text in the PDF can properly be parsed. You say, the library must be free. iText as free software requires you to respect the AGPL license.

Comment: this is for a one time thing so AGPl is a non-issue. Text is selectable (eg text) so that should work. However I'm interested in code samples if you know any.

Comment: Currently I'm only online via my smart phone. I'll try and find some sample code later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a tool for your requirements using iText.

Whenever you are looking for code samples concerning (current versions of) the iText library, you should consult [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/index.php) the code samples from which are online and searchable by keyword from [here](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keywords.php).

In your case the relevant samples are [Burst.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=129) and [ExtractPageContentSorted2.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=296).

[Burst.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=129) shows how to split one PDF in multiple smaller PDFs. The central code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("allrecords.pdf");
final String RESULT = "record%d.pdf";

// We'll create as many new PDFs as there are pages
Document document;
PdfCopy copy;
// loop over all the pages in the original PDF
int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
for (int i = 0; i < n; ) {
    // step 1
    document = new Document();
    // step 2
    copy = new PdfCopy(document,
            new FileOutputStream(String.format(RESULT, ++i)));
    // step 3
    document.open();
    // step 4
    copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, i));
    // step 5
    document.close();
}
reader.close();
```

This sample splits a PDF in single-page PDFs. In your case you need to split by different criteria. But that only means that in the loop you sometimes have to add more than one imported page (and thus decouple loop index and page numbers to import).

To recognize on which pages a new dataset starts, be inspired by [ExtractPageContentSorted2.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=296). This sample shows how to parse the text content of a page to a string. The central code:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("allrecords.pdf");
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
    System.out.println("\nPage " + i);
    System.out.println(PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i));
}
reader.close();
```

Simply search for the record start text: If the text from page contains it, a new record starts there.

Comment: Thanks, that's very handy. Your for loop needs to go until i <= n, though, or you'll leave off the very last page of your source PDF.

Comment: That should not be necessary.  As `i` is incremented inside the loop body, this Essentially already is a loop from 1 to `n` , far as `getImportedPage` is concerned.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org) has a [PDFSplit](http://pdfbox.apache.org/commandline/#pdfsplit) utility that you can run from the command-line.

Answer (score 1):

If you like Python, there's a nice library: [PyPDF2](http://mstamy2.github.io/PyPDF2/). The library is pure python2, BSD-like license.

Sample code:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader

input1 = PdfFileReader(open("C:\\Users\\Jarek\\Documents\\x.pdf", "rb"))

# analyze pdf data
print input1.getDocumentInfo()
print input1.getNumPages()
text = input1.getPage(0).extractText()
print text.encode("windows-1250", errors='backslashreplacee')

# create output document
output = PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(input1.getPage(0))
fout = open("c:\\temp\\1\\y.pdf", "wb")
output.write(fout)
fout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For non coders PDF Content Split is probably the easiest way without reinventing the wheel and has an easy to use interface: http://www.traction-software.co.uk/pdfcontentsplitsa/index.html

hope that helps.

Comment: You answer is out of context , it's not code but a software which is not appropriate here.